# VM restarted by HA after powered off from PowerCLI

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, powercli

I am using PowerCLI to "PowerOff" VMs when there is a certain event detected. When this even happens, the only thing we can do is to power off the VM and power it on again.

I use `Stop-VM -VM xxxx -Kill -Confirm:$false` to power off the VM but I noticed that HA will restart the VM after the VM powered off.

But if I manually do "Power off" in vSphere GUI on this VM when HA is turned on, it stays "powered off"

Any idea why HA will start a VM which "powered off" by PowerCLI? or `Stop-VM` is not the command for "Power Off"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested this without `-Kill`? From the [`Stop-VM` cmdlet reference](https://code.vmware.com/doc/preview?id=5060#https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/cd82421a-ee01-40a9-97c3-424ae49db692/972fed92-0e32-4993-9d35-0557c829bebd/doc/Stop-VM.html):

> Indicates that you want to stop the specified virtual machines by terminating their processes running on the ESX. You can use this parameter to stop a virtual machine that is not responding and cannot be stopped or restarted in other ways. To use the Kill parameter, you need to have a direct connection to ESX 4.1 or later.

Terminating the process directly on the host sure sounds like an event that should trigger HA. I think I would take a tiered approach to this:

```
# Some condition happens, ask nicely.
Shutdown-VMGuest -VM xxxx -Confirm:$false
...
# Ask less nicely.
Stop-VM -VM xxxx -Confirm:$false
...
# A last ditch effort.
Get-VM xxxx | Set-Vm -HARestartPriority Disabled -Confirm:$false
Stop-VM -VM xxxx -Kill -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: `Shutdown-vm` is not an option because it will go through windows shutdown process, thats where the issue is - "server hangs, no responding". the only option i have is to power off vm from host. I think actually it is better for us if it can be restarted by HA itself, so I dont have to run one more command to start the vm.

Comment: It's helpful if you add your specific requirements, restrictions and expectations to your original question.